# Javascript CreateElement(br)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a score keeper display.

I want to keep track of the score using `html` and `javascript`. I have everything figured out I think but I can't figure out why the line doesn't break here.

Relevant code:

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
var nes = document.createTextNode("---------");
scorechart.appendChild(br);
scorechart.appendChild(nc);
if(tot) {
    scorechart.appendChild(br);
    scorechart.appendChild(nes);
    scorechart.appendChild(br);
    scorechart.appendChild(tot);
}
```

(For a full view: https://hastebin.com/osuduluvaj.js)

It breaks for everything but the "------" part: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/240883852350980096/497957073481629696/sAAAAASUVORK5CYII.png
(I cant upload images yet as a new member)

Thank you :)

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Ill do this right now :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.createElement()` creates a single element, which you can only append to the DOM once.  If you want to reuse the `<br>` element you created, you need to clone it and you can insert the cloned copy into the DOM.  See: [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

```js
var score = [];

var scoreadd_button = document.querySelector('#scoreadd-button');
var scoreadd_input = document.querySelector('#scoreadd-input');

let sc1 = 0;
let sc2 = 0;

var scorechart = document.querySelector('.scores');

function totalScores() {
    var i;
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        sum += score[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

function newScore(amm) {
    score.push(amm);
    if (!score[1]) {
        var nc = document.createTextNode(amm)
    } else {
        var nc = document.createTextNode(" + " + amm);
    }

    if (sc1 == 0) {
        sc1 = amm;
    } else {
        sc2 = amm;
    }

    if (sc2 != 0) {
        var tot = document.createTextNode("= " + totalScores());
        sc1 = amm;
        sc2 = 0;
    }

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var nes = document.createTextNode("---------");
    scorechart.appendChild(nc);
    if (tot) {
        scorechart.appendChild(br.cloneNode(true));
        scorechart.appendChild(nes);
        scorechart.appendChild(br.cloneNode(true));
        scorechart.appendChild(tot);
    }
}

scoreadd_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var amm = scoreadd_input.value;
    newScore(parseInt(amm, 10));
});
```

```html
<button id="scoreadd-button">button</button>
<input type="text" id="scoreadd-input" />
<div class="scores"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed the issue by instead of using a variable just creating the element in the statement.

```
var nes = document.createTextNode("---------");
scorechart.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
scorechart.appendChild(nc);
if(tot) {
    scorechart.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    scorechart.appendChild(nes);
    scorechart.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    scorechart.appendChild(tot);
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, you discovered that each element can only be inserted into the DOM once.  See my answer that uses `Node.cloneNode()` to insert copies into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to defined unique variables for each new created element on javascript, otherwise they will counted as one.

This code should works

```js
var scorechart = document.querySelector('.scores');
  
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var br2 = document.createElement("br");
    var nes = document.createTextNode("---------");

        scorechart.appendChild(br);
        scorechart.appendChild(nes);
        scorechart.appendChild(br2);
```

```html
<span class="scores">
text before
</span>
after text
```

Comment: Why create unnecessary variables when all you want to do is clone the node so you can insert it into the DOM?

Comment: Thanks but isnt this essentially what I did when I answered it myself... it just ran as new variables?